# Linear projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-space

Let $Y\subset\mathbb{P}_{k}^{n}$ be a projective variety. We say that $Y$ is a *linear subvariety* if $I(Y)$ can be generated by linear polynomials. Now how can I show that $Y\subset\mathbb{P}_{k}^{n}$ is a linear subvariety if and only if $Y$ can be written as an intersection of hyperplanes?

Comment: Let $p_1, \ldots, p_i$ linear polynomials which generate $I(Y)$. Then $I(Y) = \bigcap_{\mu=1}^i I(p_\mu)$. Now what is $I(p)$ for a linear $p$?

Comment: Perhaps $I(P)$ will be hyperplane?

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}{}$

Comment: What I should do for it's inverse?

Comment: A hyperplane is of the form $I(p_\mu)$ for a linear $p_\mu$. If $Y = \bigcap_{\mu} V(p_\mu)$, then $I(Y) = \bigcup_{\mu} I(V(p_\mu)) = (p_1, \ldots, p_i)$.

Comment: @martini: not quite. The union of two ideals is not necessary an ideal.

Comment: I replaced *linear variety* by *linear subvariety* because this is not an absolute notion. It depends on the embedding of $Y$ in a projective space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We assume $k$ is algebraically closed.
Let $L_0,\dots,L_m$ be linear homogeneous polynomials in $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$.
Let $Y = V(L_0,\dots,L_m)$.
We claim that $P = (L_0,\dots,L_m)$ is a prime ideal.
We may assume that $L_0,\dots,L_m$ are linearly independent over $k$.
There exist linear homogeneous polynomials $L_{m+1},\dots,L_n$ such that
$L_0,\dots,L_n$ are linearly independent over $k$.
Let $y_i = L_i$ for $i = 0,\dots,n$.
Then $k[x_0,\dots,x_n] = k[y_0,\dots,y_n]$.
Clearly $y_0,\dots,y_n$ are algebraically independent over $k$.
Since $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]/P = k[y_0,\dots,y_n]/(y_0,\dots,y_m)$ is isomorphic to $k[y_{m+1},\dots,y_n]$, $P$ is a prime ideal.
By [the Hilbert Nullstellensatz for homogeneous ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106464/proving-the-nullstellensatz-for-homogeneous-ideals), $I(Y) = (L_0,\dots,L_m)$.

The converse is trivial.